# Is there a way to filter out tags?

Tags: support, tags, filtering

I've noticed that whenever I go to a generic tag, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) for example, I get questions not only regarding the Java programming language, but also Java APIs. For subjects that I have no experience with, I would like to filter them out of my feed, even if they are also tagged Java. Is there currently a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not`. (e.g. "[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)"). This appears to be the filter equivalent of using `-` in search. In fact, search results for "[java] -[android]" will show "[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)" in the filter box.

Comment: Curiosity got the better of me; `![java]` isn't applicable.

Comment: Too bad this syntax is not applicable to stackechange notification filters.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow's [**Advance Search Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/search#) makes it very clear how to exclude any tags.

You can do the following method to remove a particular tag from your search , in your case Java APIs.
The method is as follows:

> exclude -[tag]